# Print qrcode receipt on rongta thermal printer using esp32

Tags: serial-port, thermal-printer, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

As the title says I want to print qr code on my RONGTA RP330 printer. ah I connected wire from esp32 to the Rx and Tx pin of the printer motherboard.

For now I'm doing this:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "qrcode.h"

const byte rxPin = 16;
const byte txPin = 17;

HardwareSerial mySerial(1);

QRCode qrcode;
String paypalLink = "https://paypal.me/username";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  mySerial.begin(19200, SERIAL_8N1, rxPin, txPin);
  delay(1000); // Wait for the printer to initialize

  mySerial.write(27); // ESC command
  mySerial.write('3'); // Set line spacing
  mySerial.write(10);   // -2 dots (adjust as needed for tighter overlap)

  uint8_t qrcodeData[qrcode_getBufferSize(3)];
  qrcode_initText(&qrcode, qrcodeData, 3, 0, paypalLink.c_str() );

  int scale = 2; // Change this for different sizes
  for (uint8_t y = 0; y < qrcode.size; y++)
  {
    for (uint8_t x = 0; x < qrcode.size; x++)
    {
      if (qrcode_getModule(&qrcode, x, y))
      {
          mySerial.write(219);
          mySerial.write(219);
      } else {
        mySerial.print("  ");
      }
    }
    mySerial.print("\n");
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(qrcodeData); i++) {
    Serial.print(qrcodeData[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }

  mySerial.write(219);
  mySerial.print("\n");
  mySerial.print("Hello, Rongta!\n");
  mySerial.print("Hello, Rongta!\n");
  
  mySerial.write(27);  // ESC command
  mySerial.write('d'); // Paper feed
  mySerial.write(5);   // Feed 5 lines
  mySerial.write(29);  // GS command
  mySerial.write('V'); // Paper feed and cut
  mySerial.write(66);  // Feed length
  mySerial.write(1);   // Cut type (0: full cut, 1: partial cut)

  delay(1000); // Wait for the printing to complete before looping or exiting
}

void loop() {
}
```

But this code prints it as black box and there is line gaps:

```
#include <Adafruit_Thermal.h>

const byte rxPin = 16;  // Define your RX pin
const byte txPin = 17;  // Define your TX pin

HardwareSerial mySerial(1);

Adafruit_Thermal printer(&mySerial);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  mySerial.begin(19200, SERIAL_8N1, rxPin, txPin);
  delay(1000); // Wait for the printer to initialize

  // Set line spacing (0 dots for tighter spacing)
  setLineSpacing(0);

  // Print commands
  printer.println("Hello, Rongta!");

  // Print a custom graphic (replace with your graphic data)
  uint8_t graphicsData[] = {0x1C, 0x3E, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x3E, 0x1C}; // Replace with your custom graphic data
  int width = 8; // Width of the graphic in dots
  int height = 8; // Height of the graphic in dots
  printer.printBitmap(width, height, graphicsData);

  // Reset line spacing to default (30 dots)
  setLineSpacing(30);

  // Cut paper
  printer.feed(5); // Feed a few lines before cutting
  printer.cut();
  
  delay(1000); // Wait for the printing to complete before looping or exiting
}

void loop() {
  // Your loop code here
}

void setLineSpacing(int spacingDots) {
  mySerial.write(27);  // ESC command
  mySerial.write('3'); // Set line spacing
  mySerial.write(spacingDots);  // Set the line spacing in dots
}
```

I also tried bitmap or send qr code using serial but didn't work need some help from experienced people.

Comment: This page [DRIVER DOWNLOAD](https://www.rongtatech.com/category/downloads/1) seems to only have device drivers for Windows and Mac that support the rp330, but not for Linux. Is that okay? Also, the documentation included in the device driver is outdated or does not include the command to print QRCode. Please check with your vendor to see if they have the latest version of the command set documentation.